# Редактор кода для приложения

Tags: java

Мне в приложение нужно вставить редактор кода.

Подскажите, какой лучше `open source` библиотеку для этого использовать.
Попробовал: [RSyntaxTextArea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/) и JSyntaxPane

Вроде можно от NetBeans использовать как-то. Не знаю, на чем остановить выбор.
Понравилась `RSyntaxTextArea`, но документации под него маловато.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSyntaxTextArea выглядит очень неплохо и работает, кажется, тоже. И чего же документации мало? Есть [примеры](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/examples/index.php) и [javadoc](http://javadoc.fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/). Этого вполне достаточно должно быть...